# How to remove bottom border from ggplot in shiny html?

Tags: html, r, ggplot2, shiny

I'd like to have my plot and background of the Shiny app the same colour - I can do this except for a thin white line below the plot which I would like to remove.

Minimal example below.

I've tried all the different combinations of the colour and size arguments to try and make then all the same colour in the output but there is always one or more lines around the plot in the output.

```r
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(plotOutput("thisPlot", width = "50%"),
           h1("Some text"),
           style = "background-color: red")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$thisPlot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(iris) +
      geom_point(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color = Species), size = 5) +
      theme(
        plot.background = element_rect(fill = "red", color = NA, size = 0),
        panel.background = element_blank())
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I get a thin white line under the plot which I'd like to remove (the gridlines in white are fine, just the white line below the "Sepal.Length" axis label)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`color = NA` does not work.

Use:

```
plot.background = element_rect(fill = "red", color = "red", size = 0)
```

Comment: Thanks - any idea why the line only appeared at the bottom of the plot? I would have thought that with a wrong color specification it would have appeared on all sides like a border...

Comment: I too have no idea why `ggplot` behaves in this way! I was curious, and found this solution by accident. My first thought was that it might be caused by the `css` of `shiny`, but the line is in the image of the plot itself.